# Create a new password for user in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, passwords, change-password

how create new password with str_random and save in users table password?
example :

```
$newPassword = str_random(8);
    $userFind = User::all()->where('numberPhone', $request->phone);
    $userFind->password = hash::make($newPassword);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$newPassword = str_random(8);
$userFind = User::where('numberPhone', $request->phone)->first(); // assuming phone number is unique - get only one with first()
$userFind->password = Hash::make($newPassword); // you may need to check whether user exists before updating.
$userFind->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user faker to generate fake or dummy-data, find the DatabaseSeeder class inside your project folder on `/database/seeds`.

Then add this line if you're using Laravel version 7 , you have already a factory to create fake users, you can check for that inside the `/database/factories` you should have UserFactory.php file.

```
factory(App\User::class, 50)->create();
```

Now execute this command using the terminal to run the DatabaseSeeder:

```
php artisan db:seed
```